# Adding a picture in a scrartcl CV

Tags: diagrams

I'm using this nice CV template and my only issue is to add a picture in the upper right corner of the sheet.

The name can be aligned on the left in order to make room for the picture.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,final]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{scrpage2}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage{tabularx,colortbl}
\usepackage[top=3cm, bottom=3.5cm, left=2cm, right=2cm]{geometry}


\titleformat{\section}{\large\scshape\raggedright}{}{0em}{}[\titlerule]

\pagestyle{scrheadings}

\newcommand{\gray}{\rowcolor[gray]{.90}}

\renewcommand{\headfont}{\normalfont\rmfamily\scshape}

\cofoot{\lsstyle 42nd Street - New York City, NY\\
{\Large\Letter} email@email.com \  {\Large\Telefon} +11111111   }

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\textsc{\lsstyle\Huge{John Doe}} 
\section{Info}
\begin{tabularx}{0.97\linewidth}{>{\raggedleft\scshape}p{3cm}X}
\gray Name     & \textbf{John Doe}\\
Birthday   & \textbf{1st January 1900}\\
\gray Phone  & \textbf{+11111111}\\
 Email  & \textbf{email@email.com}\\
\end{tabularx}

\section{Education}
\section{Computer Languages}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

This is the desired result:
[image: Desired result]

Comment: You can use `\textsc{\lsstyle\Huge{John Doe}}\hfill\includegraphics{img}`

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: or use the `eso-pic` package to put it wherever you want on the page.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel `\hfill` is nice, but not the perfect solution due to bottom alignment. I've solved using `minipage` and `hfill`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've solved the problem using `minipage` in order to avoid bottom aligned text and `hfill` to put name and picture on the same row:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{minipage}[c]{.75\linewidth} %set percentage of line width as desired
\textsc{\lsstyle\Huge{John Doe}}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}[c]{.25\linewidth} %set percentage of line width as desired
\includegraphics[scale=0.70]{profile} %set scale as desired, picture named profile.png
\end{minipage}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```